# How to print the returned value of the function?

Tags: node.js

I am completely new to NodeJs and am trying to print the string that I have given in the return.

It is returning an empty String

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream("shopn'stop.txt")
});



function getText() {

var billString  = ""
lineReader.on('line', function (line) 
{
  // console.log('Line from file:', line);
  var tempStr = line;

  billString = billString.concat(tempStr + "\n");
  // console.log("temp " +  billString);
    });

 return billString;

}



console.log('BillString : ' +  getText());
```

How do I fix this ?

I am executing with Node filename.js

Current return :

```
BillString :
```

Answer (score 1):

NodeJs works asynchronously, which means that your `console.log` command starts right after the `getText()` command **starts**, but nothing assures you it will happen before it **ends**.

In order to print it, you need to put your console.log command inside the callback:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream("shopn'stop.txt")
});

function getText() {

  var billString  = ""
  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    var tempStr = line;

    billString = billString.concat(tempStr + "\n"); 
  });

  console.log('BillString : ' +  billString);
}
getText();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering but it returns the same result. No changes observed